# How do I get Teamcity to show list of failing tests from Cypress

Tags: teamcity, cypress

I am using

```
cypress run -- --reporter teamcity
```

In my build step (custom -> console)

Which certainly runs cypress, but when the tests fail I just get this:
[image: teamcity output]

and drilling down

[image]

I am wondering if there is a way to wire up team city and cypress so that teamcity will actually show the failing and passing tests? So that people dont have to go to the logs (or run manually) to see them?

It is sort of possible to see through artifacts (which very cool btw) but its not as clean as say the nunit break down
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this seems to have been an issue of syntax, if you use this as a build step:

```
npx cypress run --reporter teamcity
```

Then that works just fine. The double dash is only needed in certain scenarios and this isn't one of them.

if anyone else is stuck, the answer can be found [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html#Setting-up-CI).